# Python : Requesting URL and returning JSON data to the script

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to make something to request or even read the site, which gives information about the IP address and when I launch it, it gives me exceptions.
I need to get the data from the site and store it as a variable in local script.

I tried:

```
def SCAN_IP_ADRESS():
    while True:
        webURL = 'https://ip-api.com/'
        webURL = urllib.request.urlopen(webURL)
        data = webURL.read()
        JSON_object = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
        time.sleep(10)
```

> Website - https://ip-api.com/

Comment: "it gives me exceptions" - which exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this URL `webURL = 'https://ip-api.com/'` you'll get a 403 Response:

> {'status': 'fail', 'message': 'SSL unavailable for this endpoint, order a key at https://members.ip-api.com/'}

Looks like a paid API. You'll need to sign up to get a key and use SSL on your HTTP request for authentication.

If you use the [free API](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:json) for IP Geolocation and the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library I think you'll be able to get the desired information in json format.

```
import requests
import time

while True:
    webURL = 'http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=61439'
    data = requests.get(webURL).json()
    print(data)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I call this endpoint with `http://` instead of `https://` it works correctly!